# Airflow creating dynamic FileSensorAsync tasks

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow 2.3.3 with Astronomer custom modules. My goal is to build a dag that

1. Async polls for status json
2. Loads the json and continues on particular branch based on the json contents
3. Creates X number of Async poll tasks based on the json variable value

I have tried several approaches, but somehow I can't get the dynamic task creation to work as I would like it to work.

I would be grateful, if someone could have a look at my dag file and advice me how to implement this correctly or point out the flaws in my approach.

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    with DAG(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        dag_id="dynamic-dag-example",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        schedule_interval=None,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        #schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=6),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        catchup=False,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        default_args=default_args,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    ) as dag:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        def choose_branch_overall_status(**context):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            #overall_status = load_site_status_json(kwargs['site'], kwargs['timestamp'])['overall_status']                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            overall_status = context['templates_dict']['overall_status']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            if overall_status == 'ok':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                return ['overall_status_ok']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            if overall_status == 'critical':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                return ['overall_status_critical']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            return ['overall_status_undefined']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        for site in ['site1']:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            file_sensor_task = FileSensorAsync(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                task_id=f"poll_status_async_{site}",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                filepath=f"{{{{ data_interval_start.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') }}}}_{ site }.json",                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                fs_conn_id=FS_CONN_ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            @task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            def load_site_status_json(**kwargs) -> Dict:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                fs_hook = FSHook(conn_id=FS_CONN_ID)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                file_path = os.path.join(fs_hook.get_path(), kwargs['data_interval_start'].strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + f'_{ site }.json')                                                                                                                                                                        
                #file_path = os.path.join(fs_hook.get_path(), timestamp + f'_{ site }.json')                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    status_json = json.load(json_file)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    return status_json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                     
            check_overall_status = BranchPythonOperator(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                task_id = 'check_overall_status',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                python_callable = choose_branch_overall_status,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                provide_context = True,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                templates_dict={'overall_status': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract')['overall_status'] }}",                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                'angles': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract')['angles'] }}"})                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            overall_status_ok = DummyOperator(task_id='overall_status_ok')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            overall_status_critical = DummyOperator(task_id='overall_status_critical')                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            overall_status_undefined = DummyOperator(task_id='overall_status_undefined')                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            @task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            def load_angles(**kwargs) -> List:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                """Instead of this task, read angles from the xcom of load_site_status_json                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                return ['A','B','C']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            @task(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED_MIN_ONE_SUCCESS)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            def print_angle(angle):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                print(angle)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            file_sensor_task >> load_site_status_json() >> check_overall_status >> [overall_status_ok, overall_status_critical, overall_status_undefined]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            overall_status_ok >> print_angle.expand(angle=load_angles())                                            

            #for angle in load_site_status_json['angles']:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            #    - Create AsyncFileSensor that polls for file timestamp_site_angle
```

EDIT:
I found one solution using partial and expand, but it would be nice to have "for loop" solution too, so that I could continue processing each file separately.

Answer (score 0):

Took several days to get this right, but apparently the magical thing was to ask here so that my brain can figure it out. Here it is, I hope it helps someone else in the future.

```
        @task(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED_MIN_ONE_SUCCESS)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        def render_filenames():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            # TODO: add error handling when theres no angles etc.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            context = get_current_context()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            timestamp = context['data_interval_start'].strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            angles = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='load_site_status_json')['angles']                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            return [f"{ timestamp }_{ site }_{ angle }.txt" for angle in angles]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        angle_sensor_tasks = FileSensorAsync.partial(task_id="fsa", fs_conn_id=FS_CONN_ID, trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED_MIN_ONE_SUCCESS).expand(                                                                                                                                                  
            filepath=render_filenames()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        overall_status_ok >> angle_sensor_tasks >> DummyOperator(task_id="END")
```